# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I'm trying to push my app to heroku but am getting this message.

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adaptor, but the gem is not loaded.
```

But I did not. I don't have sqlite3 anywhere in my database.yml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host:  localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

My adapter name is psotgresql. I even opened the file myself

```
cat database.yml
```

I searched through the file but could not find postgresql. Here is my gemfile

```
ruby '2.1.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.0.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.1.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.1.1'

group :doc do

  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

I have pg located in the production environment here. I have ran bundle install, bundle update, git add, git commit, and git push heroku master numerous times and I still get this message.

I don't understand this. I did NOT specify sqlite3 for my database adaptor.

I'm at a loss for words.

Comment: What is the output of `grep sqlite -r ./ -i` when executed from the root of your rails application?

Comment: Did you forget to run `bundle update` to update your `Gemfile.lock` file, or did you forget to commit your changes to Git before trying to push to Heroku? If so, then this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 46):

I had to specify my sqlite3 version as 1.3.13:

`gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'`

Then run `bundle update`.

Comment: Thanks, It's resolved my problem. Also I have to specified - `Rails version: 5` & `Ruby version: 2.7`

Answer (score 10):

I've also encountered this problem. I found out that the installed sqlite3 is version 1.4.2.
To solve it, I add this code:

**gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6', '< 1.4'**

Below is my setup:

$ rails -v

```
Rails 4.2.3
```

$ gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
– RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
– RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
– INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/armano/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
– USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/armano/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
– RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/armano/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby
– EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/armano/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin
– SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/armano/.gem/specs
– SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/armano/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/etc
```

Comment: It worked for me when I was trying to start a fresh Rails 4.2.11.3 project on Ruby 2.4, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might have either:

1. forgot to run `bundle update` or `bundle install` to update your `Gemfile.lock` file, or
2. forgot to commit your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` changes to Git with `git commit` before pushing to Heroku.

If your problem is the 2<sup>nd</sup> case, then this question is a duplicate, I just have to find the canonical question around somewhere...

Comment: I had the second case...doh.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue.

I had manually removed "pg (0.17.1)" from Gemfile.lock in an attempt to cover my tracks after neglecting to put the '--without production' param in for `bundle install`.  Adding back solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue when starting a rails 5.0 tutorial on cloud9 IDE (amazon). Default sqlite3 version installed by running {rails new} within the cloud editor was 3.7.17 2013-05-20

this solved my problem : `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.0'`

After this I succeeded to launch the "yay you're on rails page"

Answer (score -1):

In test environment you not have specific DB gem. Move 'pg' gem from production and development to common.