# Heroku build error: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

### What I'm trying to do

I'm building an app with rails and deploying a non master branch to heroku master test the app in production. I didn't want to mess with master until I know what I'm doing on Heroku, therefore I deployed a feature branch.

The repository of the app [can be found here](https://github.com/BlkPingu/attendion/tree/0007/heroku) if the refernce is needed.

After any change to the **gemfile** I ran:

```
bundle update
bundle install
git add .
git commit
git push heroku 0007/heroku:master
```

The last command is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14593582/5476399) and used to push a non-master branch to herokus master. Usually this is done because you don't want to mess with master. I also asked about this a while back.[The question how to set non-master up for heroku can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136230/how-to-set-up-heroku-for-a-non-master-branch-as-test-and-then-merge-it-into-mast).

I adjusted **database.yml** to fit Heroku requirements with postgresql and sqlite3.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

My gemfile is also pretty straight foreward:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.4.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development # Added development group.
gem 'pg', group: :production # Added postgres and made it production only.
gem 'rails_12factor'

# Specifying an exact Ruby version
ruby '2.4.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Step-by-step debugging and stack navigation in Pry
  gem 'pry-byebug', platform: :ruby
  # Pry is a powerful alternative to the standard IRB shell for Ruby
  gem 'pry-rails'
  # Pretty print your Ruby objects with style -- in full color and with proper indentation
  gem 'awesome_print'
  # Add a comment summarizing the current schema to the top or bottom of each of your ActiveRecord models, Specs, factory_girl factories...
  gem 'annotate'
  # Annotate guard runs the annotate gem when needed
  gem 'guard-annotate', '~> 2.3'
  # Use for fighting the N+1 problem in Ruby
  gem 'bullet'
  # Speedup RSpec + Cucumber by running parallel on multiple CPU cores
  gem 'parallel_tests'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # bundler-audit provides patch-level verification for Bundled apps
  gem 'bundler-audit', '~> 0.6.0', require: false
  # Bundler guard allows to automatically & intelligently install/update bundle when needed.
  gem 'guard-bundler', '~> 2.1', require: false
  # compare licenses against a user-defined whitelist, and give you an actionable exception report
  gem 'license_finder', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1', require: false
  # Brakeman is an open source static analysis tool which checks Rails applications for security vulnerabilities.
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  # Better Errors replaces the standard Rails error page with a much better and more useful error page
  gem 'better_errors'
  # necessary to use Better Errors' advanced features
  gem 'binding_of_caller', platforms: :ruby
  # RuboCop configuration which has the same code style checking as official Ruby on Rails
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.51.0', require: false
  gem 'guard-rubocop', require: false
  # i18n-tasks helps you find and manage missing and unused translations
  gem 'i18n-tasks', require: false
  # IYE makes it easy to translate your Rails I18N files and keeps them up to date
  gem 'iye', require: false
  # Image Uploader Carrierwave for all kinds of Picture related jobs
  gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'



end

group :test do
  # Guard is a command line tool to easily handle events on file system modifications
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  # This gem brings back assigns to your controller tests as well as assert_template
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  # To get the default Rails tests to show red and green at the appropriate times
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  # Strategies for cleaning databases in Ruby. Can be used to ensure a clean state for testing.
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  # Code coverage for Ruby
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  # Collection of testing matchers extracted from Shoulda
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

### The problem

After testing my app locally I decided to push it to Heroku, however I'm not able to resolve a dependancy conflict.

**The suspected error:**

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
>   Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile

I know this issue has been documented on many posts. I combed through them to find what I had missed but to no avail.

These are the posts I found on this issue:

- [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336809/gemloaderror-specified-sqlite3-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-is-not-loa/27338485)
- [source 2](https://github.com/ivaldi/brimir/issues/26)
- [source 3](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/heroku-continues-to-detect-sqlite3-for-database-adapter-after-grouping-gem-in-to-dev-and-test)

They all basically say, look out that you set up postgresql as production and sqlite3 as development database or set your project up with postgres from the get go.

As far as I can tell I have this covered.

I set my gemfile to use `pg` as production database, and `sqlite3` as development database, as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/606a8948daae21fd77fe#prepare-your-rails-app-for-heroku), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941849/gemloaderror-when-trying-to-deply-on-heroku-rails-4).

My gemfile does not seem to have any production deps for sqlite.

```
 [57] → gem dependency -R sqlite
Gem sqlite3-1.3.13
  hoe (~> 3.15, development)
  hoe-bundler (~> 1.0, development)
  mini_portile (~> 0.6.2, development)
  minitest (~> 5.9, development)
  rake-compiler (~> 0.9.3, development)
  rake-compiler-dock (~> 0.5.2, development)
  rdoc (~> 4.0, development)
  Used by
    awesome_print-1.8.0 (sqlite3 (>= 0, development))
    database_cleaner-1.7.0 (sqlite3 (>= 0, development))
    rails-controller-testing-1.0.2 (sqlite3 (>= 0, development))
    sass-rails-5.0.7 (sqlite3 (>= 0, development))
```

The problems started to show when trying to run `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`.

**This is the produced trail from heroku:**

```
 [159] → heroku logs --tail
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276401+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276425+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276495+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276567+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276591+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-09-03T03:00:29.276615+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-09-03T08:35:36.524552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-09-03T08:35:39.232773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52942 -e production`
2018-09-03T08:35:42.729326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656882+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656898+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.6 application starting in production
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656899+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656900+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656943+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656967+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656977+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656980+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656982+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.656983+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657020+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657023+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657024+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657027+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657038+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657065+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657068+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657070+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657073+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657083+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657086+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657110+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657113+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657123+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657128+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657152+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657153+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657154+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `block in require_or_load'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657178+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657181+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657184+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657186+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657212+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657213+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657216+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:335:in `depend_on'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657220+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require_dependency'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657224+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657226+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657230+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657232+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657234+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657238+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657240+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657241+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657243+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657247+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657249+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657250+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657252+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657254+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657257+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657259+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657260+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657261+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657262+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657264+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657266+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657267+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657268+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657270+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657273+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657275+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657278+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657279+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657280+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657283+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657284+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657287+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657288+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657290+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657291+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657294+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657295+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657301+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657302+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657305+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657306+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657307+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657308+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657311+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657312+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657313+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657316+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.657318+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-09-03T08:35:42.704940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-03T09:52:58.423149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=attendion.herokuapp.com request_id=fc40234e-28c4-4007-a780-1731f87512d4 fwd="87.144.250.234" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-03T09:52:59.224100+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=attendion.herokuapp.com request_id=786316ef-6db5-48b9-9590-5467827cf791 fwd="87.144.250.234" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: You need to specify `postgresql` as adapter for production

Comment: AFAIC I did this in the gemfile with `gem 'pg', group: :production` . Can you set up an answer to specify where exactly I failed to do this?

Comment: In `database.yml`

Comment: can you link a source or elaborate?

Comment: You can find that in one of your linked sources

Comment: if you mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711138/5476399), I can't. I want to keep sqlite3 as development database. I should have set up the whole app with postgres from the start, but now I have to find the middle ground but can't find documentation.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. You can specify different adapters for different environments in the `database.yml`. If you look closely you will find the solution in one of your linked sources.

Comment: added `production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000` getting: `PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`

Comment: You forgot to add a host.

Comment: added `host:localhost` , got `PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused

Comment: I went there already and I either have no `postmaster.pid` in `/usr/local/var/postgres/` nor a `server.log`. I feel like I don't have a postgres database whatsoever. How to generate it from my existing development database?

Comment: fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336844/error-when-run-migrations-on-heroku-postgresql-with-rails-5

can you compose an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not work with Heroku as its disk based and Heroku uses an ephemeral file system.

> SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk.
> While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack
> has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read
> from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to
> use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least
> once every 24 hours.
>
> Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent running SQLite would still not
> be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would
> run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk
> backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would
> have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.
>
> -[Heroku Devcenter: SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Heroku provides Postgres as the free default database for rails which is as close to a recommendation as you can get.

If you are deploying to Postgres you should also be developing/testing on Postgres.

> Differences between backing services mean that tiny incompatibilities
> crop up, causing code that worked and passed tests in development or
> staging to fail in production. These types of errors create friction
> that disincentivizes continuous deployment. The cost of this friction
> and the subsequent dampening of continuous deployment is extremely
> high when considered in aggregate over the lifetime of an application.
>
> - https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

If you really want to stick with SQLite you need to configure the adapters properly:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  # nothing else is needed
```

I do not recommend this.

Comment: I'll refer to the detailed guide that Heroku has for [properly setting up postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres) - but the error you currently have is due to the fact that you are using the sqlite adapter and not  `adapter: postgresql`.