Application error with error code H10 of a ruby on rails app deployed on Heroku
I encountered an application error after having deployed my Ruby on Rails app to Heroku. The app is developed on Cloud9 from AWS and is called "wcslux_app". The app is equivalent to the hello_app from Hartl's rails_tutorial. In the Log file, I can see there is an error code H10 on GET with path "/" and ""/favicon.ico".
After having followed the tutorial my app is not working in production on Heroku. I executed following commands to deploy the wcslux_app:
source \<(curl -sL <https://cdn.learnenough.com/resize>) 
rake log:clear 
rake tmp:clear 
source \<(curl -sL <https://cdn.learnenough.com/heroku_install>) 
heroku login --interactive 
heroku create 
git push heroku main

When visiting https://sheltered-beach-35205-f93f5210b58a.herokuapp.com, I was expecting to have the same results as obtained in my development environment IDE Cloud of cloud9 of AWS.
Gem file:
group :development, :test do
   gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
   gem "debug", "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ] 
end 

group :production do 
  gem "pg", "1.3.5" 
end


heroku run rails console :  Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError).
It's unclear to me what is missing in the gem file...

Do not add the SQLite gem. SQLite does not work on Heroku due to it's ephemeral file system. What should be done is to remove SQLite from the gemfile and use Postgres in all enviroments. I wrote a longer answer on this a while back  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155604/544825

In my Gemfile I added sqlite3 only in development and test environment. Hence, this should not impact production environment. I still do not understand how to fix the problem
group :development, :test do
gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
gem "debug",   "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end
group :production do
gem "pg", "1.3.5"
end

also some housekeeping rules please do not use images of error messages and edit the question itself to add more details instead of commenting on your own question. Make it easy for people trying to help you.

@wiredforfreedomit's still a very bad idea to use different databases for testing and production as there are a lot of inconsistencies between PG and SQLite. You can either get with the program or waste time sticking with SQLite which has no real advantages except that it doesn't require any setup on unix systems.

If you really want to do it you need to setup your database.yml to use different adapters per environment.

setup of the database.yml config file was indeed the good solution

It's not actually a good solution, but whatever floats your boat.

The setup of specific adapters for each environment in the database.yml config file is the solution . I have defined a sqlite adapter for development and test environments and a Postgres adapter for production environment.
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: wcslux_app_production
  username: wcslux_app
  password: <%= ENV['WCSLUX_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. Specifically, what did you change in the database.yml file?

I changed the production: adapter: to postgresql

As max mentioned above, this is a time bomb, not a solution. Database engines aren't drop-in replacements with each other. You should use Postgres locally if you're going to use it in production.
